# The events array of jArr should contain 3 events. The array only shows the last event. How can I populate the events array with all events

Tags: javascript, json

Following is what I would like the returned array to look like.   This can be returned as an object or array. The function below tries to populate an array. It should return a JSON array. The output title media and text parts returned from the function below are right. The events array only shows the last event.

```js
deArr = {
  "title": {
    "media": {
      "url": "//www.dah.dah/photos/dah1.jpg",
      "caption": "dah dah dah dah"
    },
    "text": {
      "headline": "dah dah dah dah ",
      "text": "dah dah dah dah"
    }
  },
  "events": [{
      "media": {
        "url": "//www.dah.dah/photos/dah2.jpg",
        "caption": "dah dah dah dah"
      },
      "start_date": {
        "month": "8",
        "day": "9",
        "year": "1963"
      },
      "text": {
        "headline": "dah dah dah dah",
        "text": "dah dah dah dah"
      }
    },
    {
      "media": {
        "url": "//www.dah.dah/photos/dah3.jpg",
        "caption": "dah dah dah dah"
      },
      "start_date": {
        "month": "1",
        "day": "16",
        "year": "1978"
      },
      "text": {
        "headline": "dah dah dah dah",
        "text": "dah dah dah dah"
      }
    },
    {
      "media": {
        "url": "//www.dah.dah/photos/dah4.jpg",
        "caption": "dah dah dah dah"
      },
      "start_date": {
        "month": "7",
        "day": "28",
        "year": "1992"
      },
      "text": {
        "headline": "dah dah dah dah",
        "text": "dah dah dah dah"
      }
    }
  ]
}

function make_the_json() { // Make the JSON feed for timeline .2

  var tlStr = document.ShoTL.tlmrksStr.value; // Lines of the timeline lines are joined by a colon.

  var tlStr = tlStr.replace(/http:/g, 'http;'); //  Eliminate URL colons temporarily.
  var tlmrks = tlStr.replace(/https:/g, 'https;');

  var tlnsARR = [];
  tlnsARR = tlmrks.split('_'); // Split timeline lines into array.

  // First line must have 4 parts.  The first part is a valid URL.

  var tllnprtsARR = [];
  tllnprtsARR = tlnsARR[0].split(':'); // Split timeline first line.             

  var jArr = [];

  var title = [];
  var media = [];
  var text = [];
  var events = [];
  var startdate = [];

  media['url'] = tllnprtsARR[0];
  media['caption'] = tllnprtsARR[1];

  text['headline'] = tllnprtsARR[2];
  text['text'] = tllnprtsARR[3];

  title = [media, text];

  tllnprtsARR = [];
  media = [];
  text = [];
  var datePrts = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < tlnsARR.length; i++) {

    if (tlnsARR[i].indexOf('Analysis:') != -1) { // End loop at analysis start.
      break;
    }

    tllnprtsARR = tlnsARR[i].split(':');

    tllnprtsARR[0] = tllnprtsARR[0].replace('http;', 'http:'); //  Bring URL colons back.
    tllnprtsARR[0] = tllnprtsARR[0].replace('https;', 'https:');

    media['url'] = tllnprtsARR[0];
    media['caption'] = tllnprtsARR[1];

    datePrts = tllnprtsARR[2].split(',');
    startdate['month'] = datePrts[0];
    startdate['day'] = datePrts[1];
    startdate['year'] = datePrts[2];

    text['headline'] = tllnprtsARR[3];
    text['text'] = tllnprtsARR[4];

    events[i] = [media, startdate, text];

    tllnprtsARR = []; // Initialize.
    datePrts = [];

  }

  jArr = [title, events];

  return jArr;

}

console.log(make_the_json());
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Craig Tussey

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going in the right direction but I'm still not there.  Below is my current code and the console result.  It is part of an answer.  The data is just a test.

```
function make_the_json() { // Make the JSON feed for timeline 2.

         var tlStr = document.ShoTL.tlmrksStr.value; // Timeline lines joined by :.

         var tlStr = tlStr.replace(/http:/g, 'http;'); // Eliminate URL colons. 
         var tlmrks = tlStr.replace(/https:/g, 'https;');         

         var tlnsARR = [];
         tlnsARR = tlmrks.split('_'); // Split timeline lines into array.

         //var myJson = {title: {media: {}, text: {}}, events: [{media: {}, startdate: {month: {}, day: {}, year: {}}, text: {}}]}; // Define the objectstructure
         var myJson = {title: {media: {}, text: {}}, events: {media: {}, startdate: {month: {}, day: {}, year: {}}, text: {}}}; // Define the objectstructure

         for ( var i=0; i < tlnsARR.length; i++ ) {

           if (tlnsARR[i].indexOf('Analysis:') != -1) { // End loop at analysis start.
             break;
           } 

           var tllnprtsARR = [];
           tllnprtsARR = tlnsARR[i].split(':');

           tllnprtsARR[0] = tllnprtsARR[0].replace('http;', 'http:'); //  Bring URL colons back.
           tllnprtsARR[0] = tllnprtsARR[0].replace('https;', 'https:'); 

           if (i == 0) { // First record has 4 parts.

             myJson.title.media['url'] = tllnprtsARR[0]; // Object attribute = value. 
             myJson.title.media['caption'] = tllnprtsARR[1];
             myJson.title.text['headline'] = tllnprtsARR[2];
             myJson.title.text['text'] = tllnprtsARR[3];

           } else { // Second record forward has 5 parts.

               myJson.events.media['url'] = tllnprtsARR[0]; 
               myJson.events.media['caption'] = tllnprtsARR[1];

               var datePrts = [];
               datePrts = tllnprtsARR[2].split(',');
               myJson.events.startdate['month'] = datePrts[0]; 
               myJson.events.startdate['day'] = datePrts[1]; 
               myJson.events.startdate['year'] = datePrts[2];

               myJson.events.text['headline'] = tllnprtsARR[3];
               myJson.events.text['text'] = tllnprtsARR[4];

               //myJson.events = [{myJson.events.media}, {myJson.events.startdate}, {myJson.events.text}];

             }

         }

         var JSONobj = JSON.stringify(myJson);            

         return JSONobj;

       }
```

console result:

```
{
 "title":{"media":{"url":"http://steepusa.no-ip.info/images/myphoto2.jpg",
                   "caption":"This is me today."},
          "text":{"headline":"Cliff Craig Tussey III<br/> 1950 - ",
                  "text":"<p>I had a wonderful childhood.</p>"}
 },

 "events":{"media":{"url":"http://steepusa.no-ip.info/images/past.gif",
                    "caption":"Here is me and the old lady today."},
           "startdate":{"month":"4",
                        "day":"8",
                        "year":"2020"},
           "text":{"headline":"We are getting old.",
                   "text":"<p>We are dancing our way to hole in the ground.</p>"}
 }
}
```

I still can't insert multiple events and multiple can vary. I'm not getting the vertical formatting that I'd hoped for.   I did the formatting.  But the result looks good so far.   I'm still trying to get the syntax for multiple events.  The commented myJson and the commented last line in the loop are my most recent syntactical try to no avail.  This is my first JSON and I'm a little busy, but this attempt is better.  Thanks for any help.

craigt

Comment: Notice the specification at the top of this post does not have unique event names.

Answer (score 0):

The following function produces a JSON that conforms to the specification at the top of this post (deArr).

```
    function make_the_json() { // Make the JSON feed for timeline 2.

         var tlStr = document.ShoTL.tlmrksStr.value; // Timeline lines joined by :.

         var tlStr = tlStr.replace(/http:/g, 'http;'); // Eliminate URL colons for split. 
         var tlmrks = tlStr.replace(/https:/g, 'https;');         

         var tlnsARR = []; // Timeline lines.
         tlnsARR = tlmrks.split('_'); // Split timeline lines into array.

         var myJson = { title: {media: {}, text: {}}, events: {media: {url: {}, caption: {}}, start_date: {month: {}, day: {}, year: {}}, text: {headline: {}, text: {}} } }; // Define the object structure.

         var deEvents = []; // Events array.
         var nmEvents = tlnsARR.length;
         for ( var i=1; i < nmEvents; i++ ) {

           if (tlnsARR[i].indexOf('Analysis:') != -1) { // End loop at analysis start.
             break;
           } 

           var tllnprtsARR = [];
           tllnprtsARR = tlnsARR[i].split(':'); // Timeline line parts.

           tllnprtsARR[0] = tllnprtsARR[0].replace('http;', 'http:'); //  Bring URL colons back.
           tllnprtsARR[0] = tllnprtsARR[0].replace('https;', 'https:'); 

           if (i == 0) { // First record has 4 parts.              

             myJson.title.media['url'] = tllnprtsARR[0]; // Load title parts. 
             myJson.title.media['caption'] = tllnprtsARR[1];
             myJson.title.text['headline'] = tllnprtsARR[2];
             myJson.title.text['text'] = tllnprtsARR[3];

           } else { // Second record forward has 5 parts.               

               myJson = myJson = { title: {media: {}, text: {}}, events: {media: {url: {}, caption: {}}, start_date: {month: {}, day: {}, year: {}}, text: {headline: {}, text: {}} } }; 

               myJson.events.media['url'] = tllnprtsARR[0]; // Load event parts.
               myJson.events.media['caption'] = tllnprtsARR[1];           

               var datePrts = [];
               datePrts = tllnprtsARR[2].split(',');
               myJson.events.start_date['month'] = datePrts[0]; 
               myJson.events.start_date['day'] = datePrts[1]; 
               myJson.events.start_date['year'] = datePrts[2];

               myJson.events.text['headline'] = tllnprtsARR[3];
               myJson.events.text['text'] = tllnprtsARR[4]; 

               deEvents.push(myJson.events); // Put the labeled event into the array of events.

             }

         }

         myJson = myJson = { title: {media: {}, text: {}}, events: {media: {url: {}, caption: {}}, start_date: {month: {}, day: {}, year: {}}, text: {headline: {}, text: {}} } }; 
         myJson['events'] = deEvents; // Replace the events object space with the full labeled event set. 

         var tllnprtsARR = [];
         tllnprtsARR = tlnsARR[0].split(':'); // Timeline line parts.

         tllnprtsARR[0] = tllnprtsARR[0].replace('http;', 'http:'); //  Bring URL colons back.
         tllnprtsARR[0] = tllnprtsARR[0].replace('https;', 'https:'); 

         myJson.title.media['url'] = tllnprtsARR[0]; // Load title parts. 
         myJson.title.media['caption'] = tllnprtsARR[1];
         myJson.title.text['headline'] = tllnprtsARR[2];
         myJson.title.text['text'] = tllnprtsARR[3];               

         //myJson = JSON.stringify(myJson); // Convert it to literal JSON object form for testing.   

         return myJson;

       }
```

Notice I store the fully qualified events in an array and put the array into the myJson events object replacing the last event assigned in the loop.  The result follows.

```
    {
      "title": {
        "media": {
          "url": "http://steepusa.no-ip.info/images/myphoto2.jpg",
          "caption": "This is me today."
        },
        "text": {
          "headline": "Cliff Craig Tussey III<br/> 1950 - ",
          "text": "<p>I had a wonderful childhood.</p>"
        }
      },
      "events": [
        {
          "media": {
            "url": "http://steepusa.no-ip.info/images/healthxx.jpg",
            "caption": "This is my wife and son soon after he was born."
          },
          "start_date": {
            "month": "9",
            "day": "17",
            "year": "1977"
          },
          "text": {
            "headline": "We were a family.",
            "text": "<p>It was a fine time.</p> "
          }
        },
        {
          "media": {
            "url": "http://steepusa.no-ip.info/images/meoneiffeltower.jpg",
            "caption": "This is my son grown up.  As you can see, he has gone tipsey."
          },
          "start_date": {
            "month": "2",
            "day": "23",
            "year": "1996"
          },
          "text": {
            "headline": "This is him in Paris on the Eiffel Tower",
            "text": "<p>He was on an educational trip to India, Japan, and Europe.</p>"
          }
        },
        {
          "media": {
            "url": "http://steepusa.no-ip.info/images/past.gif",
            "caption": "Here is me and the old lady today."
          },
          "start_date": {
            "month": "4",
            "day": "8",
            "year": "2020"
          },
          "text": {
            "headline": "We are getting old.",
            "text": "<p> "
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Thanks everyone for taking a look at this.

craigt